# Dynamically Linking GLEW with CMake

Tags: c++, windows, opengl, cmake, clion

I've looked over Stack Overflow and Google to try to figure this out, but everything I've seen regarding a dynamic linking either doesn't work or they end up static linking.

```
E:/CLion/GLEW-Test/main.cpp:8: undefined reference to `_imp__glewInit@0'
E:/CLion/GLEW-Test/main.cpp:12: undefined reference to `_imp__glewGetErrorString@4'
E:/CLion/GLEW-Test/main.cpp:14: undefined reference to `_imp__glewGetString@4'
```

I am trying to dynamically link GLEW using CLion. The problem is, I've grown up with Visual Studio so I've never really had to think much about it. I'm trying to teach myself CMake and OpenGL, so this would have been a perfect exercise.

I downloaded the source for GLEW and built it with CMake and MinGW. I placed the resulting `glew32.dll` in `C:/Windows/System32/`, and I placed the `libglew32.a` in `C:/MinGW/lib`, and I placed `glew.h`, `glxew.h`, and `wglew.h` into `C:/MinGW/include/GL`.

Currently, I also have the libraries `glew32.dll`, `libglu32.a`, and `libopengl32.a` in my build directory.

Here is my CMakeLists.txt:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.8)
project(GLEW_Test)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11)
set (CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -Wall -Wextra")
set( CMAKE_VERBOSE_MAKEFILE on )

set(SOURCE_FILES main.cpp)
add_executable(GLEW_Test ${SOURCE_FILES})
target_link_libraries(GLEW_Test glew32 glu32 opengl32)
```

and this is my main.cpp:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <GL/glew.h>

int main()
{
    std::cout << "Hello, World!" << std::endl;

    GLenum err = glewInit();
    if (GLEW_OK != err)
    {
        /* Problem: glewInit failed, something is seriously wrong. */
        fprintf(stderr, "Error: %s\n", glewGetErrorString(err));
    }
    fprintf(stdout, "Status: Using GLEW %s\n", glewGetString(GLEW_VERSION));

    return 0;
}
```

Now, if I `#define GLEW_STATIC` before I `#include <GL/glew.h>`, the program compiles and outputs the expected output (An error for having no GLContext).    However, to my knowledge, that is static linking, and I want to dynamically link GLEW.  This is what I see when I compile without `#define GLEW_STATIC`:

```
"C:\Program Files\JetBrains\CLion 2017.2.2\bin\cmake\bin\cmake.exe" --build E:\CLion\GLEW-Test\cmake-build-debug --target GLEW_Test -- -j 2
"C:\Program Files\JetBrains\CLion 2017.2.2\bin\cmake\bin\cmake.exe" -HE:\CLion\GLEW-Test -BE:\CLion\GLEW-Test\cmake-build-debug --check-build-system CMakeFiles\Makefile.cmake 0
C:/MinGW/bin/mingw32-make.exe -f CMakeFiles\Makefile2 GLEW_Test
mingw32-make.exe[1]: Entering directory 'E:/CLion/GLEW-Test/cmake-build-debug'
"C:\Program Files\JetBrains\CLion 2017.2.2\bin\cmake\bin\cmake.exe" -HE:\CLion\GLEW-Test -BE:\CLion\GLEW-Test\cmake-build-debug --check-build-system CMakeFiles\Makefile.cmake 0
"C:\Program Files\JetBrains\CLion 2017.2.2\bin\cmake\bin\cmake.exe" -E cmake_progress_start E:\CLion\GLEW-Test\cmake-build-debug\CMakeFiles 2
C:/MinGW/bin/mingw32-make.exe -f CMakeFiles\Makefile2 CMakeFiles/GLEW_Test.dir/all
mingw32-make.exe[2]: Entering directory 'E:/CLion/GLEW-Test/cmake-build-debug'
C:/MinGW/bin/mingw32-make.exe -f CMakeFiles\GLEW_Test.dir\build.make CMakeFiles/GLEW_Test.dir/depend
mingw32-make.exe[3]: Entering directory 'E:/CLion/GLEW-Test/cmake-build-debug'
"C:\Program Files\JetBrains\CLion 2017.2.2\bin\cmake\bin\cmake.exe" -E cmake_depends "MinGW Makefiles" E:\CLion\GLEW-Test E:\CLion\GLEW-Test E:\CLion\GLEW-Test\cmake-build-debug E:\CLion\GLEW-Test\cmake-build-debug E:\CLion\GLEW-Test\cmake-build-debug\CMakeFiles\GLEW_Test.dir\DependInfo.cmake --color=
mingw32-make.exe[3]: Leaving directory 'E:/CLion/GLEW-Test/cmake-build-debug'
C:/MinGW/bin/mingw32-make.exe -f CMakeFiles\GLEW_Test.dir\build.make CMakeFiles/GLEW_Test.dir/build
mingw32-make.exe[3]: Entering directory 'E:/CLion/GLEW-Test/cmake-build-debug'
[ 50%] Linking CXX executable GLEW_Test.exe
"C:\Program Files\JetBrains\CLion 2017.2.2\bin\cmake\bin\cmake.exe" -E cmake_link_script CMakeFiles\GLEW_Test.dir\link.txt --verbose=1
"C:\Program Files\JetBrains\CLion 2017.2.2\bin\cmake\bin\cmake.exe" -E remove -f CMakeFiles\GLEW_Test.dir/objects.a
C:\MinGW\bin\ar.exe cr CMakeFiles\GLEW_Test.dir/objects.a @CMakeFiles\GLEW_Test.dir\objects1.rsp
C:\MinGW\bin\g++.exe  -Wall -Wextra -g   -Wl,--whole-archive CMakeFiles\GLEW_Test.dir/objects.a -Wl,--no-whole-archive  -o GLEW_Test.exe -Wl,--out-implib,libGLEW_Test.dll.a -Wl,--major-image-version,0,--minor-image-version,0 @CMakeFiles\GLEW_Test.dir\linklibs.rsp
CMakeFiles\GLEW_Test.dir/objects.a(main.cpp.obj): In function `main':
E:/CLion/GLEW-Test/main.cpp:8: undefined reference to `_imp__glewInit@0'
E:/CLion/GLEW-Test/main.cpp:12: undefined reference to `_imp__glewGetErrorString@4'
E:/CLion/GLEW-Test/main.cpp:14: undefined reference to `_imp__glewGetString@4'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
mingw32-make.exe[3]: *** [GLEW_Test.exe] Error 1
CMakeFiles\GLEW_Test.dir\build.make:98: recipe for target 'GLEW_Test.exe' failed
mingw32-make.exe[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/GLEW_Test.dir/all] Error 2
mingw32-make.exe[3]: Leaving directory 'E:/CLion/GLEW-Test/cmake-build-debug'
mingw32-make.exe[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/GLEW_Test.dir/rule] Error 2
CMakeFiles\Makefile2:69: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/GLEW_Test.dir/all' failed
mingw32-make.exe[2]: Leaving directory 'E:/CLion/GLEW-Test/cmake-build-debug'
CMakeFiles\Makefile2:81: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/GLEW_Test.dir/rule' failed
mingw32-make.exe[1]: Leaving directory 'E:/CLion/GLEW-Test/cmake-build-debug'
Makefile:120: recipe for target 'GLEW_Test' failed
mingw32-make.exe: *** [GLEW_Test] Error 2
```

What am I doing wrong? I followed the guide at [glew's sourceforge](http://glew.sourceforge.net/install.html), and placed the .dll in my System32 folder. Since I built with CMake and MinGW, I have .a files instead of .lib files, and I stuck those in my MinGW/lib directory. 
**The only thing I didn't do (because I wasn't sure), was do nothing with my libglew32.dll.a**
Is this the culprit? I'm not sure what to do with it, and googling for information on a .dll.a file turned up nothing.

Comment: Normally, you'd increase the verbosity of `make` to see the actual compiler invocations and then run them manually to find the right options. The `make VERBOSE=1` is used for that. You can try the same with `mingw32-make.exe` probably like that: `cmake.exe --build E:\CLion\GLEW-Test\cmake-build-debug --target GLEW_Test -- -j 2 VERBOSE=1` because `cmake.exe --build` is basically a `make` invocation. About the libraries: I think that it should be `target_link_libraries(GLEW_Test libglew32 libglu32 libopengl32)` for any configuration (the static or dynamic linking is decided somewhere else).

Comment: I've updated the verbose output. I don't see anything different. It still looks like it can't resolve some glew functions after linking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, so after googling around a bit and trying to understand what a .dll.a file is, I've got it figured out!

This is what I did to dynamically link glew using CMake:

1. I deleted `glew32.a` from my `C:\MinGW\lib` directory, and replaced it with `glew32.dll.a`
2. I placed `glew32.dll` into my build folder. However, you can also have it in your `SysWOW64` folder and it should work.

And that's all! My CMakeLists.txt is still the same.

Answer (score 3):

```
target_link_libraries(GLEW_Test libglew32.a libglu32.a libopengl32.a)
```

You should never include "lib" prefix and the file extension of a library in your target_link_libraries. Instead you should do it like this

```
target_link_libraries(GLEW_Test glew32 glu32 opengl32)
```

as cmake already will search for e.g. glew32.dll, libglew32.a by itself then. This way, you also stay platform/compiler independent.

For testing/bughunt purpose, I would recommend that you put the required libraries in the directory of your executable first and check if the error still occurs, since the windows linker [searches the executable's directory first](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7d83bc18.aspx) for libraries.

If it does not occur anymore but does when the libraries are located in the other locations, be sure that those locations are part of the PATH environmental variable.

Comment: That makes sense. I was on the fence about putting the "lib" prefix on them. 
So, I've stuck the following into my build dir: `glew32.dll`, `libglu32.a`, and `libopengl32.a`. However, I am still getting the same overall error: Undefined references to glew functions (`undefined reference to `_imp__glewInit@0'`). 

So, for whatever reason, it's finding and linking the program correctly, but cannot resolve these functions?

Comment: There was a libglew32.dll.a in my glew build output directory, any idea what that is for? I don't see any record of it on the glew site

Comment: Did you try changing the order of linked libraries? Especially with static libraries I think the order matters.

Comment: I've not done that, I'll give it a try when I get home.